# Centripetal Force Terminology

Tags: forces, terminology

Is centripetal force the correct terminology? Why is the resultant (orthogonal ) force component called "centripetal force"? In my view, it is just a component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terminology is correct. It doesn't have to be the resultant force. You are correct that it may only be a component. "The centripetal force" is just a name we give to the sum of all forces that point towards the centre (thus the name) because only these forces cause turning. Regardless of other forces being present in other directions.

- Imagine driving around a round-about. Constant speed. Friction pulls you inwards as you turn your wheels and causes the turning. This is thus the centripetal force. In this case it is also the resultant force because all other forces (weight and normal force) cancel out.
- Now speed up. Accelerate. Your wheels push from the asphalt and a forwards friction force appears. The resultant force is now not towards the centre but at an angle. Only a portion of the total friction force points sideways towards the centre and causes turning. Another portion points forwards and causes speeding up. So only the centre-directed portion is called the centripetal force.

Answer (score 1):

Centripetal is the name given a force when that force acts to keep an object moving at constant velocity, moving in a circle.  The actual force can be gravity, tension in a string, etc.

More generally, centripetal force refers to the component of the total force that is directed toward the center, and the total motion may not be circular.